# sum of counts on daily basis

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I need to calculate the sum of counts of unique userids for calculating the monthly unique users and this needs to be done on a daily basis. That is for today it wil have to show the sum from 30 days before from today and for yesterday, it needs to calculate the sum beginign from 30 days before yesterday.

like for today it should start counting from 27-04-2013 and for yesterday it is from 26-04-2013. The table strucutre is like following :

```
date        uid   visits
27-04-2013   11     45
27-04-2013   11     45
26-04-2013   11     45
25-04-2013   11     45
24-04-2013   11     45
```

this is something like the running total ,but for 30 days only.

I have used **`DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL -30 day)`** like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT date,COUNT(uid) FROM tablename 
WHERE DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL -30 day) AND date GROUP BY date
```

but for this I am getting diferent results compared to this query.

```
SELECT COUNT( `uID` )
FROM tablename
WHERE date
BETWEEN '2013-04-27'
AND '2013-05-27'
```

This is for COUNT only. I need to calculate the SUM of the counts.

Comment: Which query gives the correct result: the 1-st or the 2-nd?

Comment: @user4035 The second one as it is calculating counts directly for the given dates.

Comment: @AlwinAugustin "calculate the sum of counts of unique userids" - so the correct result for the sample data in your question would be 4, because user 11 visited in four days?

Comment: @Mifeet in this case it is 1 as the same user visits every day. I actually need the unique users for the 30 day period.

Comment: @AlwinAugustin : **Let me clarify.. You want a user id (uid) who has visited daily (for 30 days CONTINOUSLY)... right??**

Comment: @AlwinAugustin alright, if you need the number of unique visitors in a month, that `COUNT(DISTINCT uid)` should be enough, right? It returns 1 for your example. See my updated answer.

Comment: @FahimParkar it is like this : If user 11 and 12 visits totday, then we need to check if these IDs are unique for the 30 days. so it is an overall count of the uniques for that 30 day time period.

Comment: @AlwinAugustin : Ok, I will create database in mysql-fiddle like that and let you know..

Comment: @AlwinAugustin : I have updated my answer... hope this is what you want...

Answer (score 4):

***Please don't use MySQL reserve keywords in column name. Hence I have changed `date` to `myDate` in my query.***

I believe for the first step you are looking as below.

```
select myDate, sum(visits) as 'Total Visits' from tablename GROUP BY myDate;
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a805/3)

---

For last month data, use below query.

```
select myDate, sum(visits) as 'Total Visits' from tablename
GROUP BY myDate
HAVING myDate BETWEEN '2013-04-27' AND '2013-05-27';
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a805/7)

---

I hope this is what you are looking.

```
select myDate, uid, COUNT(visits) as 'Total Visits' from tablename
GROUP BY myDate
HAVING myDate BETWEEN '2013-04-27' AND '2013-05-27';
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80224/3)

---

### I hope this is what you want

```
select * from tablename 
GROUP BY uid
HAVING 
COUNT(DISTINCT myDate)>=30 
AND
myDate BETWEEN '2013-04-27' AND '2013-05-27';
```

**For Demo purpose, I have used 3 days data in below Demo link.**

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c057/5)

Note: Changes would be on below lines

```
COUNT(DISTINCT myDate)>=3
                        ^^ --> This would be number of days in month (as I am using 3 days only, I have 3)
```

&

```
myDate BETWEEN '2013-04-27' AND '2013-04-29';
                ^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I think for `myDate BETWEEN '2013-04-27' AND '2013-04-29';` you should use `date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL -30 day) AND CURDATE()` as per Mifeet answer.

Comment: Are you sure, that he needs the SUM of visits? He  said, he needs to count the unique uids per 30 days and then sum them.

Comment: it is not the sum of visits. It is the SUM of count of unique uids.

Comment: @AlwinAugustin : I have updated answer.. Please let me know if this is what you are looking?

Comment: actually I need something like this SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `uID` ) as I need the sum of counts

Comment: @AlwinAugustin : considering my data at sqlfiddle, can u tell me what output you are expecting? **you meant total number of unique visitors in a month?**

Comment: The sum of counts should be 2 as we have only 11 and 12 as unique

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30690/discussion-between-alwin-augustin-and-fahim-parkar)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell from the question whether you are trying to get this for a single day or for all days in the past.  If the latter, here is one way you can do it:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL n.n day) as thedate,
       COUNT(distinct uid) as numUsers, sum(visits) as totVisits
FROM tablename t cross join
     (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all
      select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all
      . . .
      select 27 union all select 28 union all select 29
     ) n 
group by DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL n.n day) ;
```

Your first query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date,COUNT(uid)
FROM tablename 
WHERE DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL -30 day) AND date
GROUP BY date
```

Has two shortcomings.  First, the `where` clause is not a boolean.  I think you mean something like:

```
where date between DATE_ADD(now(),INTERVAL -30 day) AND now()
```

Also, you don't need a `distinct` (and should not have one!) when using a `group by`.

EDIT:

So, run this in your Fiddle to see that it returns the numbers for each day in the data (with 6 days of history rather than 30):

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(mydate, INTERVAL n.n day) as thedate,
       COUNT(distinct uid) as numUsers, sum(visits) as totVisits
FROM tablename t cross join
     (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all
      select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 
     ) n 
where DATE_ADD(mydate, INTERVAL n.n day) < now()
group by DATE_ADD(mydate, INTERVAL n.n day) ;
```

You'll notice that it skips dates that have no users.

Comment: for all days in the past . Like past 7 days, past 30 days or between towo specified dates based on a filter. so I need to add all the datesi in the query ?

Comment: @AlwinAugustin . . . If you want just one row for the most recent dates, then you can use a variation of the queries in your question.  This solution is showing how to get values for all dates in the data, by using a numbers table.  If you have to do this regularly for any number of days, then create a numbers table with a sufficiently large set of numbers in it.

Comment: so I neeed to create another table with dates ? dates are already in my table. please check this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60230/1

Comment: I actually need is 10 for 27th May 9 for 26th May and 9 upto 10 because there is no dates in between